# How to bypass the DTD validation in Java( Maybe related to Spring MVC)?

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, xsd, dtd

I used Spring MVC developing a simple web service application. I have been developing and testing on my local environment, everything is fine.

However, yesterday I deployed my war package into the Tomcat of our host server, our server has no connectivity to any internet address. Thus, when I hit the index page, the error shows at the console, saying cannot connect to "www.springframework.org", thus cannot download the DTD to do the validation.

I was thinking to make the DTD local and change the path in the XML declaration. But I don't think it is a wise solution.

Wonder if there is any way that I can use to avoid the DTD downloading and validation here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: as the DTD will not change, hosting local seems like a solution.

Comment: It should be getting the DTD from your JARs, not from the network. The network is usually plan B. Check your configuration.